# error Array to string conversion in php category and subcategory

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have complies  php code which gives a array to string conversion error , creating category and sub category tree node but while compiling occurs the error , let me explain where i got the error.

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','res_user','Res@123','res_db');
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql = " SELECT * , category.id AS catId FROM category INNER JOIN sub_category ON category.id = sub_category.category_id
ORDER BY category.id, sub_category.category_id";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$categoryArray = array();
$oldCatId = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if ($row['catId'] != $oldCatId) {
        $categoryArray[$row['catId']] = array(
            'success' => true,
            'category_' . $row['catId'] = array(
        'cat_id' => $row["catId"],
        'cat_name' => $row['cat_name'],
        'cat_img' => $row['cat_img'],
        'sub_category' => array(
            'sub_id' => $row['category_id'],
            'sub_name' => $row['sub_name']
        )
            )
        );
        $oldCatId = $row['catId'];
    } else {
        $categoryArray[$row['catId']]['category_' . $row['catId']]['sub_category'][] = array(
            'sub_id' => $row['category_id'],
            'sub_name' => $row['sub_name']
        );
    }
}
   echo $categoryArray;


?>
```

Comment: What is the error ? Please paste the error you are getting

Comment: what is the error and at what point does it occur?

Comment: on echo the  $categoryArray it gives error ,Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\phpxamp\htdocs\sachin\cate_subcate.php on line 26

Comment: you have to print_r ($categoryArray) or echo $categoryArrray[0] .... echo not print entire array it will print particular position of array

Answer (score 0):

you cant [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)'s, as **its for outputting one or more strings**, you need to [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it, as:

```
print_r($categoryArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is that the code is trying to display an array with **echo**. This construct was designed only for displaying strings, not arrays.  As long a you provide PHP with a scalar value (boolean, int, string, float) , if the scalar's data type is not a string, PHP will temporarily promote it to being a string.

Normally you need to iterate through an array to display any scalar values of its elements, writing some kind of looping structure.  PHP offers a great convenience for working with multidimensional arrays, the function *array_walk_recursive()* which works with a callback.  Here's a variation of the array mentioned in the question to give you an idea about how to use array_walk_recursive() with a callback.  Now that PHP supports anonymous functions, we can use one for the callback, as follows:

```
    <?php
    $categoryArray[0]['category_0']['sub_category'][] = array(
            'sub_id' => 500,
            'sub_name' => '1a'
        );
    array_walk_recursive($categoryArray,
                function($value,$key){
                  echo "$key: $value\n";

                });
    // output:
    sub_id: 500
    sub_name: 1a
```

What's great about array_walk_recursive() is that it will walk through a multidimensional array and the callback displays any available data. Note, the callback needs its parameters in a certain order, the first parameter must correspond to an element's value while the second must represent its key.

Also see live demo [here](http://3v4l.org/YuHsj#v530).